# WiFi with Raspberry and Ubuntu

Tags: wireless, raspberrypi

I created a Python app to control a robot arm with a Raspberry running Ubuntu. I need to be able to connect to the Raspberry remotely using WiFi, and preferably Windows Remote Desktop Connection. I've done that with Raspberrys running Raspberrian but I can't figure out how to do it with Ubunto.

Can anyone here help with that?

I don't know how to find the Ubuntu version. It's using Xfce 4.12. It's a Raspberry pi 4.

I am able to reach it with Putty, but I don't know the username and password. It boots automatically.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Which version of Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? You can get the version by `cat /etc/lsb-release`.

Comment: Thank you. It says it's Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS. I'm digging around with info I found trying to determine the username and password.

It's a Raspberry Pi 4.

Comment: I found my username and changed my password. I can connect with Putty now, but now with Remote Desktop Connection. I've done that with Raspberrian but it's obviously different with Ubuntu.

Comment: I installed xrdp and Remote Desktop Connection appears to connect but then Remote Desktop Connection shuts down on the PC. If I log out on Ubuntu first, Remote Desktop Connection appears to connect but then it goes back to the connect screen.